# Updating an atomic< int >, what memory ordering do I have to use?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I have an `atomic< int > position;` and I want to increase it by one in the same thread:

```
void increasePosition()
{
    int temp;
    temp = position.load( memory_order_consume );
    position.store( ++temp, memory_order_release );
}
```

Can I do it that way or am I making a mistake? Is the memory ordering correct?

Comment: The way you increment the counter is not atomic: another thread could modify `position` between load and store. Why not simply `++position`?

Comment: if your operation is atomic any memory ordering you pick will not change the outcome of your atomic operation. memory ordering affects the overall performances and business logic of the concurrency inside your application not just 1 atomic operation.

Comment: `++position` works. I thought one needs to load or store atomic - variables for any changes. - Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`atomic_fetch_add`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_fetch_add/) here, or else you're not getting atomicity.